# Dynamic script never fires load callback

Tags: javascript

Here is a simplified version of my problem. Why isn't the `loaded` callback fired?

My goal is to inject a script file - which I can't reference by `src` - in to the `head` tag of the document:

```
(function(module, scriptContent, loaded) {

    if (!window[module]) {

        var script = document.createElement('script'),
            head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

        if (script.readyState) {
            script.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (script.readyState === 'loaded' || script.readyState === 'complete') {
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    loaded();
                }
            };
        } else {
            script.onload = loaded;
        }

        script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptContent));
        head.appendChild(script);
    } else {
        loaded();
    }
})('foo', 'var foo = {};', function(){
    console.log('loaded');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/on23j3wk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because inline scripts are run synchronously, and so don't use `readyState`.

This can be demonstrated by changing your `'var foo = {};'` to `'console.log("b")'`, and adding `console.log('a')` before, and `console.log('c')` after `head.appendChild(script);`:

```js
(function(module, scriptContent, loaded) {

    if (!window[module]) {
     
        var script = document.createElement('script'),
            head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            
        if (script.readyState) {
            script.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (script.readyState === 'loaded' || script.readyState === 'complete') {
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    loaded();
                }
            };
        } else {
            script.onload = loaded;
        }
        
        script.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptContent));
        console.log('a');
        head.appendChild(script);
        console.log('c');
    } else {
        loaded();
    }
})('foo', 'console.log("b")', function(){
 console.log('loaded');
});
```

Note how they're all logged in alphabetical order.
If the inserted script were loaded asynchronously, the call stack that created it would have to terminate first, which would lead to "a" and "c" being logged before "b".

In other words, you can call `loaded()` right after `head.appendChild(script);`.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. I guess I won't be needing a callback in this case then :)